# Next.js class rendering bug, Why is the class applied to another element?

Tags: typescript, sass, next.js, styled-components, server-side-rendering

In the condition in which one element is displayed, and the other should not, is assigned to the class of the neighboring element
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkAK8.png)

There is a login button component with a border gradient. I have an avatar component

[button auth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Dzu.png)

[avatar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFwaC.png)

The avatar component, when initially loading the page, has the same class as the authorization component.

[mutating component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Pq7Y.png)

However, it is not in the code. If we switch to other pages, this bug disappears. The error occurs in both dev hmr and prod

This bug occurs in many places.
In the project styled-components, classnames, scss, bootstrap, mui. Soon we will get rid of boostrap && scss;
Build next.js, server side rendering, typescript,

There is another example
[Initial download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBwrl.png)

[After page navigating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Olv7.png)

Answer (score 0):

there is special instruction on how you can use `styled-components` in next.js and in general, SSR. Keep in mind that `styled-components` does its job during the runtime and this does not go down well with serverside rendering and you need to pretender the styles in order for them to work well.

Use [this link](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#nextjs) to go to styled-components official instructions for next.js and use [this link](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/main/examples/with-styled-components) to see an official example of using `styled-components` with next.js.

Keep in mind if you ended up using the given links to set up your project and you are using next.js 12+ you need to make some small changes. You are no longer able to use babel since next.js stopped using babel to render your project instead you need to use the `next.config.js` file. By setting `experimental.styledComponents` to `true` you no longer have to use the babel file.

```js
/** @type {import("next").NextConfig} */
const config = {
    experimental: {
        styledComponents: true,
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```